# Title page with University Logo

Tags: titles, logos

I am a beginner at latex and I realize that similar questions were asked previously, but I don't really understand what to do. Here is the code for a sample titlepage that does not work for me: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~cap/spl/titlepage.tex Here is an example of how a thesis titlepage should look like: http://othes.univie.ac.at/32753/1/2014-04-16_0348909.pdf The first error I get is ! LaTeX Error: File `RZ_Logo_Uni_sw' not found. Was this a file of the person who wrote the thesis? I did download the University logo on my computer and wrote the name of the file in its place: \includegraphics{uni_logo_farbe_01}. I get the same error message.

I still get an error message after removing \includegraphics altogether: Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete. Nevertheless, I definitely need the uni logo, but it seems this is not the only problem.

Comment: Are you putting this in another document, or compiling it standalone? The title page as it stands is not a compilable document. All LaTeX documents need to have a `\documentclass`, and a `\begin{document}` and an `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage.tex} %Following the advice given in the template

\end{document}
```

This compiles fine, if you add in a title and a name in the corresponding code blocks (between `% >>>>> BEGINN TITEL >>>>>` and ``` %``The Creation of a Title Page'' ``` and the same for the author:

```
\LARGE{\textsf{  % Hier kommt der eigentliche Titel, bei Bedarf mit \\
                 % ACHTUNG: Deutsche Anfuehrungszeichen: ,,Titel``
                 %          English quotes:              ``title''
    % >>>>> BEGINN TITEL >>>>>
    This is my Title
    %``The Creation of a Title Page''
    % <<<<< ENDE TITEL <<<<<
}}
```

The blank line in the template is causing the trouble, it marks a new paragraph.

Comment: Everything now works in the demo version. I still cannot get the actual university logo. I downloaded it on my computer at https://public.univie.ac.at/logo/ as a tif file (it was the only option that let me download). The latex error says file not found.

Comment: @AndrewChiriac LaTeX cannot include `tif` images, you need to convert it (for example to `png`).

Comment: Is that the only problem? Does Latex know exactly what to do once an image is downloaded on my computer? Do you recommend a free and safe way to convert it?

Comment: @AndrewChiriac No, you're right, you need to tell LaTeX where it finds the file. So either you put the image in the same folder as your `tex` file, or you give full path (absolute or relative) to `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @AndrewChiriac For the conversion: Safe? That depends :) If you google for "tiff to png" you find free online converters, not sure if you regard this as safe. If you are on Linux, you might try imagemagick, I suppose.

Comment: Actually, I found a jpg version which works fine.